# (Swift) Strange feedback when drag&drop NSOutlineview

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

First of all, sorry for my English, I'll try my best to make it clear.(Edited with @Chip Jarred's suggestion，I've made some changes to simplify my question)

What I managed to do is achieving NSOutlineview drag & drop method, using .gap style(I just want to use this style!):

```
outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap
```

And problems occurred, it could be easier described by a gif:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0avhJ.gif

You can see drag&drop can run partly correctly. But the problem is: **when I drag a node to the bottom of the list, a bit more below Node4, it will be dragged to the top of the list.**

I've tried to fix it so I inserted a "print" fuction in validatDrop{}:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                   validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, 
                   proposedItem item: Any?, 
                   proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {

    print("item:\(item),index:\(index)")

    if index < 0 && item == nil{
        return []
    }else{
        outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap
        return .move        
    }
}
```

The terminal told me that when I dropped a node to the top of the list or the bottom of the list, it returned a same index:

> item:nil,index:0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pI7s.gif

And if I delete the .gap style:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                 validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, 
                 proposedItem item: Any?, 
                 proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {

    print("item:\(item),index:\(index)")

    if index < 0 && item == nil{
        return []
    }else{
        // outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap //ignore this line
        return .move        
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8MMe.gif

Everything became normal. So it could be deduced that it could be not my "move" method's problem.

Sorry for English again, I would be grateful for any help.

And here is the essential part of my code:

```
outlineView.registerForDraggedTypes([.string])

...

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                 heightOfRowByItem item: Any) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
...

extension SceneCatalogView{

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                 pasteboardWriterForItem item: Any) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
    let sourceNode = outlineView.row(forItem: item)
    return "\(sourceNode)" as NSString
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                 validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, 
                 proposedItem item: Any?, 
                 proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {
    if index < 0 && item == nil{
        return []
    }else{
        outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap
        return .move        
    }
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
                 acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, 
                 item: Any?, 
                 childIndex index: Int) -> Bool {

    let pasteboard = info.draggingPasteboard
    let sourceNode = Int(pasteboard.string(forType: .string)!)!
    let source = outlineView.item(atRow: sourceNode) as? Catalog
    let content = source?.content
    let targetNode = outlineView.row(forItem: item)

    moveNode(sourceNode, targetNode, index) // Not finished
    outlineView.reloadData() // Not finished

    return true
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that things return to normal if you delete the `.gap` style, do you mean you delete only the line setting that style or that you delete the entire `if` surrounding it?

Comment: Sorry I may make sth. wrong description, I deleted the if{}, retaining “return move”, the pointer would become the default blue line style, and when I drag a node lower than the last node of the list, the blue line no longer change and just stay below the last node. If I insert a print method, I can get a correct return such as "item:nil,index:4", and will not return the first row index any more.

Comment: Is the problem solved then?

Comment: Yes but unsatisfied, I want to figure out why I cannot use the .gap style, I prefer .gap style.

Comment: I think I understand, but to make sure there is no language barrier, perhaps you can post the `outlineView(_:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedIndex:)` with the `.gap` deleted.

Comment: This may work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFy0Q.gif

Comment: I finally posted my answer.  I made the mistake of trying to do it in an Xcode playground.  I should have known that would be trouble.  Every time I use playgrounds I have endless problems.  Eventually I just made a regular Xcode project.

Comment: Try `if index < 0 || item == nil`  in `validateDrop`.

Comment: Nope, "item == nil" returns the parent items' indices, that will disable dragging method between parent items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found multiple reports of a bug with `NSTableView` when using the `.gap` dragging style.  It would seem that `NSOutlineView` is inheriting that bug.  In any case, I found a work-around.

[image]

The problem is that when you drag below the last top-level item, the `item` and `childIndex` passed to  `outlineView(_:acceptDrop:item:childIndex)` are always `nil` and `0`, which are exactly the same values you get when dragging to the top of list.  The only way I could find to differentiate between the two cases was to use the `draggingLocation` from `NSDraggingInfo` to compare against the first item's cell frame, and use that to translate the `index`.

```swift
func translateIndexForGapBug(
    _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
    item: Any?,
    index: Int,
    for info: NSDraggingInfo) -> Int
{
    guard outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle == .gap,
          items.count > 0,
          item == nil,
          index == 0
    else { return index }
    
    let point = outlineView.convert(info.draggingLocation, from: nil)
    let firstCellFrame = outlineView.frameOfCell(atColumn: 0, row: 0)
    return outlineView.isFlipped
        ? (point.y < firstCellFrame.maxY ? index : items.count)
        : (point.y >= firstCellFrame.minY ? index : items.count)
}
```

I call it in `outlineView(_:acceptDrop:item:childIndex)`:

```swift
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
        item: Any?,
        childIndex index: Int) -> Bool
    {
        assert(item == nil || item is Item)
        
        trace("item = \(String(describing: item)), index = \(index)")
        guard let sourceTitle = info.draggingPasteboard.string(forType: .string),
              let source = parentAndChildIndex(forItemTitled: sourceTitle)
        else { return false }
        
        let debuggedIndex = translateIndexForGapBug(
            outlineView,
            item: item,
            index: index,
            for: info
        )
        moveItem(from: source, to: (item as? Item, debuggedIndex))
        outlineView.reloadData()

        return true
    }
```

Since other drag styles seem to work, I only do this if it's set to `.gap`, so for the sake of testing, my `outlineView(_:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex:)` looks like this:

```swift
func outlineView(
    _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
    validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
    proposedItem item: Any?,
    proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation
{
    trace("item = \(String(describing: item)), index = \(index)")
    guard info.draggingSource as? NSOutlineView === outlineView else {
        return []
    }
    
    outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap

    if item == nil, index < 0 {
        return []
    }
    return .move
}
```

However instead of setting it to `.gap` every time, you could probably just set it once when you set the data source in your outline view.

My definition of `Item` should be equivalent to your `Catalog`.

```swift
//------------------------------
class Item: CustomStringConvertible
{
    var description: String { title }
    var title: String
    var children: [Item] = []
    
    //------------------------------
    init(_ title: String) { self.title = title }
    convenience init(_ id: Int) { self.init("Item \(id)") }
    
    //------------------------------
    func addChild() {
        children.append(Item("\(title).\(children.count + 1)"))
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func parentAndChildIndex(forChildTitled title: String) -> (Item?, Int)?
    {
        for i in children.indices
        {
            let child = children[i]
            if child.title == title { return (self, i) }
            if let found = child.parentAndChildIndex(forChildTitled: title){
                return found
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here's full implementation of my data source:

```swift
//------------------------------
@objc class OVDataSource: NSObject, NSOutlineViewDataSource
{
    //------------------------------
    // Just creating some items programmatically for testing
    var items: [Item] =
    {
        trace()
        let items = (1...4).map { Item($0) }
        items[2].addChild()
        items[2].addChild()
        return items
    }()
    
    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        pasteboardWriterForItem item: Any) -> NSPasteboardWriting?
    {
        trace()
        guard let item = item as? Item else { return nil }
        return item.title as NSString
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int
    {
        trace()
        if let item = item {
            return (item as? Item)?.children.count ?? 0
        }
        return items.count
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        child index: Int,
        ofItem item: Any?) -> Any
    {
        trace()
        if let item = item as? Item {
            return item.children[index]
        }
        return items[index]
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool
    {
        trace()
        if let item = item as? Item {
            return item.children.count > 0
        }
        return false
    }

    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
        proposedItem item: Any?,
        proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation
    {
        trace("item = \(String(describing: item)), index = \(index)")
        guard info.draggingSource as? NSOutlineView === outlineView else {
            return []
        }
        
        outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap

        if item == nil, index < 0 {
            return []
        }
        return .move
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func outlineView(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
        item: Any?,
        childIndex index: Int) -> Bool
    {
        assert(item == nil || item is Item)
        
        trace("item = \(String(describing: item)), index = \(index)")
        guard let sourceTitle = info.draggingPasteboard.string(forType: .string),
              let source = parentAndChildIndex(forItemTitled: sourceTitle)
        else { return false }
        
        let debuggedIndex = translateIndexForGapBug(
            outlineView,
            item: item,
            index: index,
            for: info
        )
        moveItem(from: source, to: (item as? Item, debuggedIndex))
        outlineView.reloadData()

        return true
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func translateIndexForGapBug(
        _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
        item: Any?,
        index: Int,
        for info: NSDraggingInfo) -> Int
    {
        guard outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle == .gap,
              items.count > 0,
              item == nil,
              index == 0
        else { return index }
        
        let point = outlineView.convert(info.draggingLocation, from: nil)
        let firstCellFrame = outlineView.frameOfCell(atColumn: 0, row: 0)
        return outlineView.isFlipped
            ? (point.y < firstCellFrame.maxY ? index : items.count)
            : (point.y >= firstCellFrame.minY ? index : items.count)
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func parentAndChildIndex(forItemTitled title: String) -> (parent: Item?, index: Int)?
    {
        trace("Finding parent and child for item: \"\(title)\"")
        for i in items.indices
        {
            let item = items[i]
            if item.title == title { return (nil, i) }
            if let found = item.parentAndChildIndex(forChildTitled: title) {
                return found
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    func moveItem(
        from src: (parent: Item?, index: Int),
        to dst: (parent: Item?, index: Int))
    {
        trace("src = \(src), dst = \(dst)")
        
        let item: Item = src.parent?.children[src.index]
            ?? items[src.index]
        
        if src.parent === dst.parent  // Moving item in same level?
        {
            if let commonParent = src.parent
            {
                moveItem(
                    item,
                    from: src.index,
                    to: dst.index,
                    in: &commonParent.children
                )
                return
            }
            
            moveItem(item, from: src.index, to: dst.index, in: &items)
            return
        }
        
        // Moving between levels
        if let srcParent = src.parent {
            srcParent.children.remove(at: src.index)
        }
        else { items.remove(at: src.index) }
        
        if let dstParent = dst.parent {
            insertItem(item, into: &dstParent.children, at: dst.index)
        }
        else { insertItem(item, into: &items, at: dst.index) }
    }
    
    //------------------------------
    // Move an item within the same level
    func moveItem(
        _ item: Item,
        from srcIndex: Int,
        to dstIndex: Int,
        in items: inout [Item])
    {
        if srcIndex < dstIndex
        {
            insertItem(item, into: &items, at: dstIndex)
            items.remove(at: srcIndex)
            return
        }
        
        items.remove(at: srcIndex)
        insertItem(item, into: &items, at: dstIndex)
    }
            
    func insertItem(_ item: Item, into items: inout [Item], at index: Int)
    {
        if index < 0
        {
            items.append(item)
            return
        }
        items.insert(item, at: index)
    }
}
```

The `trace()` calls are just for debugging.  Either remove them, or implement it:

```swift
func trace(
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    function: StaticString = #function,
    line: UInt = #line)
{
    #if DEBUG
    print("\(function):\(line): \(message())")
    #endif
}
```

Comment: I convert .mov to .gif via an app called Permute. Or I'll find some way to  leave a my email via DM, but I'm familiar with stackoverflow as a newer. Anyway I deely appreciate for your help! I‘ll make some tests.

Comment: Thanks I downloaded a random app from the App Store.  It put a water mark in, but that's fine for this.  I'll check out Permute, though this one seems kind of nice.  It does more than gifs, and can do screen recording itself.  I might just do the in-app purchase to remove the water marks.

Comment: Thx for ur answer again, and I've got your gif, pretty nice reference but, probably it's my fault, did we make some misunderstandings: What confuses me most is that the .gap style give me a wrong feedback when I drag a node to the bottom of a list, but the regular style won't happen! I need to confirm that if I have clearly stated my question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the test I tried with the altering the drag validation method.  I updated my answer with an update at the bottom.

Comment: Would you mind upload a project package for me to do some deeper research, it will a big help!

Comment: I'll put it on GitHub.  Just let me know when you have solved your problem so I can delete the repo.

Comment: It's on GitHub now: `git clone https://github.com/chipjarred/StackOverflowOutlineView.git`

Comment: Actually that might be a good place if you have questions about the source code.  You can just add an issue, and we can have an extended discussion there.

Comment: I sincerely thanks for your patience. I've spent a week or two searching for relevant codes on Github, but I've found nothing valid yet.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or just a drag & drop code sample without `.gap`?

Comment: My question still needs more discussion so far.

Comment: From what I could tell, the bug is not in your code, but with `NSOutlineView`, or rather it inherits it from `NSTableView`.   I've implemented a work-around that I believe gives the desired behavior.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.  If you do a `git pull` on the repo, you'll get the work-around..

Comment: @Willeke, at first I misunderstood what the problem was.  That's been clarified now, and I think my updated answer addresses the actual problem.

Comment: Solved! I hope you can update this answer at your convenience, to help who "unfortunately" encounter similar problems.